# Calling function in mapPartition Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scala function as follows:

```
def variance (reg: Int, samRecords: Array[SAMRecord]) : 
    Array[(Int, (Int, String))] =
{
  // Body of the function
}
```

I am trying to call this function in the mapPartition method as follows:

```
//SortedOut is RDD[(Int,(Int,Int,SAMRecord))]
val Out = SortedOut.mapPartitions(iter=> {val inArr = iter.map(x=>x._2._3).toArray
                                        val inReg = iter.map(x=> x._1).toArray
                                        if (inArr.length != 0)
                                        {
                                        println("Calling function")
                                        variantCall(inReg(0),inArr).iterator
                                       }
                                       else
                                        iter}).cache
```

I have checked that SortedOut has non empty partitions but still, the functional call is not taking place. Why is this code not working? I want to call this function for each of the partitions, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger the computation only when you do some Action.

do `collect` or `count` or `foreach` etc at the end to trigger evaluation

Notice collect at the end

```
val Out = SortedOut.mapPartitions(iter=> {val inArr = iter.map(x=>x._2._3).toArray
                                        val inReg = iter.map(x=> x._1).toArray
                                        if (inArr.length != 0)
                                        {
                                        println("Calling function")
                                        variantCall(inReg(0),inArr).iterator
                                       }
                                       else
                                        iter}).cache.collect
```